# How to get my divs to space the save even with different content

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where I have to make a *grid like system* which will allow all the `div.cons` to be spaced the same even if their height is different.

This is the current code that I am working with ([jsfiddle mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/2p1cvh7j/)):

```css
html, body {
    position:relative;
}
html {
 background-color:#FFF;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#333;
}
p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4,h5, h6, li, td, th, div,img {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
p, h1, h2, h3, h4,h5, h6, li, td, th, div,img {
    cursor:default;
}
p, a, li, td, th, div {
    font-size:12px;
}
div.nav > ul li > p,
div.nav > ul li > a,
a {
    font-family:inherit;
 font-weight:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
}

div.wrapper {
 width:510px;
 min-height:200px;
 height:auto;
 overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
 margin:auto auto;
}
 div.wrapper > div.con {
  width:250px;
  height:auto;
  overflow:auto;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-top:10px;
 }
 div.wrapper > div.con.odd {
  margin-right:10px;
 }
  div.wrapper > div.con > h1.title,
  div.wrapper > div.con > p.content {
   display:block;
   padding:5px 10px;
  }
  div.wrapper > div.con > h1.title {
   margin-bottom:20px;
   background-color:#000;
   font-weight:700;
   font-size:14px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   color:#FFF;
  }
  div.wrapper > div.con > p.content {
   font-size:12px;
   text-align:center;
  }
  div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt {
   height:auto;
   overflow:auto;
   margin-top:20px;
   background-color:#000;
  }
   div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt > ul {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    list-style-type:none;
   }
    div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt > ul > li {
     display:inline-block;
     font-weight:700;
     font-size:10px;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     color:#FFF;
    }
     div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt > ul > li > a {
      display:block;
      padding:2px 5px;
     }
     div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt > ul > li > a:hover {
      color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
     }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="con odd">
         <h1 class="title">
             Aenean id nulla nibh. Nam.
            </h1>
            <p class="content">
             Etiam vestibulum, ex vitae dapibus imperdiet, massa risus finibus ex, ut faucibus dolor ex eget mi. Praesent lectus diam, imperdiet eget gravida eget, pulvinar vitae dolor. Nam nunc lorem, cursus eget nisl in, pretium aliquet libero. Cum sociis cras amet.
            </p>
            <div class="opt">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Perm Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="con">
         <h1 class="title">
             Aenean id nulla nibh. Nam.
            </h1>
            <p class="content">
             Aenean convallis, felis ac luctus dictum, nisi risus convallis enim, ac condimentum quam mi ac dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis et sed.
            </p>
            <div class="opt">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Perm Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="con odd">
         <h1 class="title">
             Aenean id nulla nibh. Nam.
            </h1>
            <p class="content">
             Ut at suscipit sem. Mauris quis sollicitudin enim. Sed eu ante id massa vestibulum cursus. Phasellus mollis ullamcorper maximus. Curabitur eu fermentum arcu. Vestibulum placerat a dolor vel vulputate. Praesent leo lectus, vulputate posuere.
            </p>
            <div class="opt">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Perm Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="con">
         <h1 class="title">
             Praesent aliquet leo ut lacus ornare, ac venenatis lacus gravida.
            </h1>
            <p class="content">
             Pellentesque consequat sapien nec sapien volutpat iaculis. In at est dapibus, scelerisque purus sed.
            </p>
            <div class="opt">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Perm Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

An example image of what I mean:
[image: Example Image]

The first red arrow, to the left, is what the spacing should be.
The second red arrow, to the right, is the issue I am having.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: @susheel - "even if their height is different."

Comment: @susheel - I am hoping for a css only fix. Quit trying to start an argument...

Comment: Use a table. This is what they are for.

Comment: @gaynorvader - pretty sure a table would have the same issue.

Comment: A quick solution might be to use 2 column `div`s side by side, and then fill them alternately.

Comment: @zxc actually, no, tables don't have that issue because they are tables. They are meant to divivde into squares. Your best bet, however, is javascript as there's no good way to this in CSS. Its a simple bit of javascript to write, but doing this in CSS is not feasible.

Comment: you can css margin or padding for the content.

Comment: the only way to obtain what u want using `float:left` and **css** alone is using `margin-top` with `-ve` values and you know  this cant be dynamic

Comment: Look into using flexbox here.

Comment: Here's an example using a table http://jsfiddle.net/2p1cvh7j/4/

Comment: @gaynorvader that forced the same height onto every div in the row, i said "even if their height is different."

Comment: @zxc Ah, now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create a Masonry-style layout similar to Pinterest? If so [this tutorial](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) will show you exactly how to do it. [Here's what you'll end up with](http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/).

The demo markup is as follows:

```
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item">Neque, vitae, fugiat, libero corrupti officiis sint facilis tempora quidem repudiandae praesentium odit similique adipisci aut.</div>
   <div class="item">Incidunt sit unde minima in nostrum?</div>
   <div class="item">Ducimus, voluptates, modi, delectus animi maiores consequuntur repellat quisquam fugiat eum possimus enim culpa totam praesentium magni quae!</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicta dolore adipisci hic ipsam velit deleniti possimus cumque accusantium rerum quibusdam.</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, praesentium consequatur ducimus commodi quam ex illo omnis dicta reiciendis vel nesciunt deserunt aut sequi nam mollitia perferendis ipsam possimus temporibus!</div>
   <div class="item">Ab, adipisci, temporibus eaque quis harum perferendis incidunt cupiditate doloribus dolor numquam voluptates ipsum dolore aspernatur et voluptate ipsam beatae animi culpa.</div>
</div>
```

Now we make use of the CSS properties `column-count` and `column-gap` which are applied to the parent element to determine the number of columns in your layout:

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

you then need to apply this style to each child:

```
.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The tutorial also provides a link to a [JS fallback](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for older browsers

and that's all you need to create a Masonry-style layout :)

Answer (score 1):

please see the fiddle. I have added some CSS3 properties to the wrapper div.

https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/2p1cvh7j/1/

```
div.wrapper {
    width:510px;
    min-height:200px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Good attempt. The issue with OP's layout (besides multiple H1 tags and so many direct descendant rules, which makes layout very difficult to modify) is that they actually need to match the height of the 'div.con.odd > p.content' container with that of the next sibling [div.con]'s  'p.content' container, and there's really no way to do that without JS or fixing the height/position of h1s and div.opts.

Comment: @Sidd: I think the scenario is about the overall div height. that what I tried to sort out in my solution. If I am wrong please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split into 2 columns and maintain your div's inside that like this:
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2p1cvh7j/2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="width50">...
  </div>
 <div class="width50">.... 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.width50{
     width:250px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 `div` columns with `class="col"`. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p1cvh7j/5/).

You will need to account for the new divs in the heirarchy in your css with all the `>` symbols too.

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 520px;
    ...
}

div.wrapper > div.col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.wrapper > div.col.odd {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col odd">
        <div class="con">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="con">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="con">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="con">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` on the `div.wrapper`, and add a `padding-bottom:20px;`

```
div.wrapper {
    width:510px;
    min-height:200px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And now add a `position:absolute` and `bottom:0px` to `div.opt`

```
div.wrapper > div.con > div.opt {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    /*margin-top:20px;*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

> [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ufdztg8a/)